# How can a return statement of a Python function keep strings in the same line like print(argument, end='')?

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, return, return-value

I am fresh off the coding boat and I am attempting to have the return values of a python function all print on one line. I know to use print(argument, en= ''), although I cannot include a print function in the return of a defined function.

Ultimately I am trying to get each first item of a list in a list, then the second and so on to print the design turned 90 degrees. I am first getting each list in a for loop then getting each index from there and printing in a second for loop.

With the code the way I have it now, I get the result I need, but there is "None" at the end of each line because I have a print function in a function instead of a "return" so I can have each index value printed on one line per list. I am curious about how to have the values displayed on one line without using the end argument of a print function in a function return. And I would always love to see a better/faster way to achieve this result.

`..OO.OO..
 .OOOOOOO.
 .OOOOOOO.
 ..OOOOO..
 ...OOO...
 ....O....`

Thank you!

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.',],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.',],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.',],
        ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.',],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.',],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.',],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',]]

xLength = len(grid[0])-1
yLength = len(grid)-1

listX = list(range(0, xLength))
listY = list(range(0, yLength))


def listGrid(y = 0):
    for x in grid:
        print(x[y], end = '')

for num in listX:
    print(listGrid(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *return a value* from the function - if a function does not return anythin, it returns `None` implicitly. Your code prints the "data" inside the function and you print the return of the function by

> ```
> print(listGrid(num))  # prints None
> ```

Print the results of your function outside, using `end=""` is an option:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.',],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.',],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.',],
        ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.',],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.',],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.',],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',]]

xLength = len(grid[0])  # fix, do not subtract 1 - range is upper border exclusive 
yLength = len(grid)-1

listX = list(range(0, xLength))
listY = list(range(0, yLength))

def listGrid(y = 0):
    return [x[y] for x in grid]  # return a list

for num in listX:
    for r in listGrid(num): 
        print(r, end="")
    print()
```

---

Or you leverate [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) to make columns from your rows and print them:

```
# directly operates on your data - you do not need anything of your code beside 
# the grid definition  
for c in zip(*grid):
    print(''.join(c))
```

Output:

```
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

Comment: Thanks, Patrick! This makes sense. The only question I have would be why the final print() in the for loop takes each value and prints it on new lines. Without the final print() I realize everything is printed on one line. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @alan The print with end="" prints each single character of a line. the print() after it only prints a newline once a line is complete